# Why does my iframe appear above my overlay?

Tags: css

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/d6P8L/1/

I'm embedding flash / html5 content via an iframe that youtube suggests to use for embedding. The problem is, my app has some overlays, but the iframe pushes itself on top of the overlays. Why does this happen? and How can I get the embed stuff to be below the overlay?

Comment: What browser? Works fine for me in FF6

Comment: oh. Chrome-dev version. 15 something. I don't have this problem in safari.

Comment: oh, it works in IE7 too. That's surprising. Maybe it's just a problem with chrome-dev being TOO new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to test this since I don't have a browser exhibiting the problem however I recall a solution where by you pass a wmode parameter in the querystring to the youtube video and also add a wmode attribute to the iframe.

Such that:

```
<iframe src="[...]?wmode=transparent" wmode="opaque">
```